# ImportError when importing in python notebook, but import works fine in terminal?

Tags: python, linux, import, terminal

The import works when I call it from the command line, but when I call the import in the ipynb I get the following error:

ImportError: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have already added the path to libmkl_intel_lp64.so to my bashrc file, so I am not sure what else I can do to fix this import error in the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line `python` interpreter,
and your `jupyter notebook` kernel,
have different environments.

Use one of these techniques to help you debug the path problem:

1. `$ python -m site` (from bash prompt)
2. `import sys; from pprint import pp; pp(sys.path)` (within a cell)

---

Do yourself a favor, and use [conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/) to manage your environment.
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Be sure to `conda activate myfavoriteenvironment`
before you start the jupyter kernel.

Comment: Hello I have used sys.executable in the notebook and the terminal and got the same thing for both (~/anaconda3/bin/python). I have not used conda environments before so would this mean they are both in the base environment?

Comment: Something is different between interpreter and kernel, for example the python executable that is running, or sys.path, or LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var, or the process effective UID.

Comment: I see, the sys.path is in fact different in the terminal and notebook.  It seems that the ipynb sys.path contains none of the paths I have added to the bashrc. Though even after adding in the path to libmkl_intel_lp64.so to the notebook's sys.path I still get the importError.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use conda. It was designed to solve _exactly_ the difficulty you are now facing.